# Trying to use newtype to pass off existing data type as my own

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to wrap up a [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) in my own `newtype` in order to hide unnecessary features.

MyQueue.hs (some parts ommitted):

```
00 import Data.Sequence

10 newtype MyQueue a = Seq a

23 empty :: MyQueue a
24 empty = Data.Sequence.empty
```

I get the following error. It appears that I cannot return a [Seq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq) type and pass it off as my own type. But then how do I map my own functions to those in Data.Sequence?

```
MyQueue.hs:24:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘MyQueue a’
                  with actual type ‘Seq a4’
    • In the expression: Data.Sequence.empty
      In an equation for ‘empty’: empty = Data.Sequence.empty
    • Relevant bindings include
        empty :: MyQueue a (bound at MyQueue.hs:24:1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually did not create a `newtype` to wrap the `Seq a` into, you constructed a type `MyQueue a` that has a *data constructor* `Seq` that takes an `a`. So it can basically store anything.

You likely want to define a `MyQueue` data constructor that contains a `Seq a`, like:

```
newtype MyQueue a = MyQueue (Seq a)
```

Then you can define your `empty` as:

```
empty :: MyQueue a
empty = MyQueue Data.Sequence.empty
```

Note that the `MyQueue` in **boldface** is the data *constructor* whereas the `MyQueue` after the `::` is the *type constructor*.